# Domain Controller issues: Can't join Domain, change password, access printers. Why?

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, domain, domain-controller

For the last week, we have found ourselves in a sticky spot with Windows XP machines on a Windows Server 2003 Active Directory. Our computers can't join the domain, change passwords, or anything like that. What could possibly be wrong. Both our primary and secondary domain controllers are on and online. Help!

Comment: Look in the event logs of the DCs and the workstations that can't be added and post anything possibly relevant as an update to your question.

Answer (score 1):

try using DCDIAG.exe infomation is found here at Microsoft. [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc776854(WS.10).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc776854%28WS.10%29.aspx)

Can you login as the domain admin and make other changes? 
Has anyone gone in and made chages to the DNS/DHCP/permissions in the past week or so?

and possibly Netdiag.exe /fix

Comment: Running DCDIAG remotely results in this: LDAP bind failed with error 8341.

Comment: There may be a replication error or a firewall issue.  repadmin.exe /showrepl dc* /verbose /all /intersite > c:\repl.txt
start c:\repl.txt

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the results on that look try this (excerpt below)
http://forums.techarena.in/active-directory/45533.htm
1. Demote or reinstall the machine(s) that were disconnected.
2. Use the "repadmin /removelingeringobjects" tool to remove inconsistent
deleted objects and then resume replication.
3. Resume replication. Inconsistent deleted objects may be introduced. You
can continue replication by using the following registry key. Once the
systems replicate once, it is recommended that you remove the key to
reinstate the protection.
Registry Key:
HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\NTDS\Parameters\Allow Replication
With Divergent and Corrupt Partner